# Could somebody please help me prove $\frac{a}1=a$ using the properties of real numbers introduced in elementary algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to prove the following useful property of real numbers:

For every real number $a$, prove $\frac{a}{1} =a,$

where for all real numbers a and b: $\frac{a}{b}=a*\frac{1}{b}; b\neq0,$

and $\frac{1}{b}$ is the reciprocal or multiplicative inverse of $b.$

Comment: $1$ is the neutral element of multiplication hence $1=1^{-1}$ and hence $a\cdot 1^{-1}=\frac{a}{1}=a\cdot 1=a$

Comment: $a/1=b\to a=1\times b$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real numbers form a field; so, lets prove the proposition for an arbitrary field.

Here's the basic facts we know about the multiplicative structure of any field, where $x'$ is notation for the reciprocal of $x$.

1. $\forall xyz : (xy)z=x(yz)$
2. $\forall x(1x = x),\;\; \forall x(x1=x)$
3. $\forall x(x \neq 0 \rightarrow xx' = 1),\;\;\forall x(x \neq 0 \rightarrow x' x = 1)$
4. $\forall xy : xy=yx$
5. $1 \neq 0$

Three comments:

Firstly, you'll note that there is redundancy in the above list (in particular, each version of axiom 2 follows from the other, given 4; similarly, each version of axiom 3 follows from the other, given 4). But that's cool; you don't always have to define things a minimal way. In fact, the pursuit of minimalism can sometimes make things harder than they need to be. That said, you should always search for minimal characterizations after defining something.

Secondly, You may be more familiar with the "existential" version of axioms 2 and 3, namely

$$\exists 1\forall x (x1 = x \wedge 1x=x \wedge \forall x(x \neq 0 \rightarrow \exists y(xy=1)))$$

respectively. I think this is a perfect example of how the pursuit of minimalism can overcomplicate things. Much better the to include reciprocation and the multiplicative identity as part of the data, since this involves less fooling around. Furthermore, (this comment will probably go over your head though) specifying the additional data (in this case, the multiplicative identity $1$ and the reciprocation function) typically gives us a better idea of what homomorphisms of our structures ought to be, especially if this additional data allows us to express our axioms in a weaker fragment of first-order logic (which in this case it does, since there is no existential quantification in the approach I am advocating).

Thirdly, you may be interested to know that, as it turns out, not every structure satisfying the five given axioms can occur as the multiplicative structure of a field. Basically, this is because (but this may also go over your head) there may not exist a suitable Abelian group structure on the underlying set that interacts correctly with multiplication such that the overall result is a field.

Onwards.

Let $F$ denote a field. Your question is (basically): if $a \in F$, how do we know that $a/1 = a$?

First, lets define division. Consider $a,b \in F$ with $b \neq 0$. Then $b'$ is well-defined. Thus by 4, we see that $ab'=b'a$. So lets define that for all $a$ and all non-zero $b$, we have that $$\frac{a}{b}$$ equals either of these two expressions, and therefore both.

Note in particular that since $1 \neq 0$, we have that $\frac{a}{1}$ is always well-defined, for all $a \in F$.

Okay, lets go ahead and prove your result. Let $a \in F$ be fixed but arbitrary. Then to show $\frac{a}{1} = a$, we may argue as follows.

$$\frac{a}{1} = a1' = a1 = a$$

The only step that isn't clear is $1' = 1,$ so lets verify this.

We know from axiom 3 that

$$\forall x(x \neq 0 \rightarrow xx'=1)$$

Thus we may deduce that $$1 \neq 0 \rightarrow 11' = 1.$$

But the hypothesis of the above implication holds, since its just axiom 5. Thus

$$11' = 1.$$

Finally, recall that axiom 2 reads

$$\forall x(1x=x)$$

Thus $$11'=1',$$ and therefore $1 = 1',$ as required.

Comment: Meh, nevermind.

Comment: It is a theorem that $-a= (-1)a$, not a definition.

Comment: @TedShifrin, that actually brings up an interesting question. If, instead of asserting that every element has an additive inverse, we assert only that $1$ has an additive inverse, can we, by defining $-a = (-1)a,$ thereby prove that every element has an additive inverse? We sure can! Observe $(-a)+(a) = (-1)a+(1)a = (-1 + 1)a = 0a = 0$.

Comment: @skullpatrol: Absolutely. I would not really call these things theorems — perhaps baby propositions/exercises. But I wanted to emphasize that they are to be deduced from the standard axioms. And, true, user18921.

Comment: @skullpatrol, good point. I don't think we can guarantee that $0a = 0$ without assuming that $0a$ has an additive inverse, or at least that it is cancellative. The usual argument is $0a = (0+0)a=0a+0a$, so $0+0a = 0a +0a$, thus by cancellativity we have $0=0a$. Therefore, if we're only going to assume that $1$ has an additive inverse, we had better compensate by assuming that $0$ is a multiplicatively absorbing element.

Comment: @skullpatrol, okay I rewrote my answer. Hope the new version is more useful to you. Please comment if the notation (etc.) needs clarification or if you have any questions.

Comment: @skullpatrol, I think Stefanos & I have given better answers, because they're much closer to the axioms that I'm familiar with, and I think they're conceptually simpler that 685252's approach (although we've both provided a lot of context, so our answers look more complicated). Anyway, feel free to choose whichever answer you like; if 685252's answer is simpler to you, then it probably deserves the bounty.

Comment: @skullpatrol, you're welcome! Feel free to ask any questions you like; even if its very basic like "What is a field?" or some such.

Comment: @skullpatrol, thank you my friend. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

The set $\mathbb{R}$ of the real numbers is a [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach) $F$ meaning that addition and multiplication are defined and have the [usual properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Definition_and_illustration). According to the above link in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Definition_and_illustration) *division is defined implicitly in terms of the inverse operation of multiplication*. Among the axioms that are used to give a formal definition of an (additive and multiplicative) field, we will make use of the following two in order to prove the required result:

1. Existance of multiplicative identity element. *There is an element, called the multiplicative identity element and denoted by $1$, such that for all $a$ in $F$, $$a \cdot 1 = a$$*
2. Existence of multiplicative inverse. *For any a in $F$ other than $0$, there exists an element $a^{−1}$ in $F$, such that $$a \cdot a^{-1} = 1$$ The elements $a \cdot b^{−1}$ are also denoted by $\frac{a}{b}$. In other words division operation exists.*

So, returning to the question, by substituting $a=1$ in the first property we have that $$1\cdot 1=1$$ which implies based on the second property that $$1^{-1}=1$$ i.e. that $1$ is the multiplicative inverse of itself (which if assumed known, then all the preceding can be omitted). Using the notation in bold (second property) we have that $$\frac{a}{1}=a\cdot 1^{-1}=a\cdot1=a$$ which proves the required equality.

Comment: @skullpatrol You are welcome. About 685252's answer my opinion is that he uses practically the same property as the rest of us, but he does not give sufficient explanations or references to the axioms/definitions/notations of the multiplicative inverse and the fraction. Otherwise I do not see any mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{a}{1}=a*\frac{1}{1}$ because $\frac{a}{b}=a*\frac{1}{b}$.

$1*\frac{1}{1}=1$ because $a*\frac{1}{a}=1$.

$1*1=1$ because $a*1=a$.

Comparing the two equations above:
$\frac{1}{1}=1$.

$\therefore$ $\frac{a}{1}=a*\frac{1}{1}=a*1=a$.

Answer (score 1):

you can use induction i guess. This proof works only if we can establish that $ \frac11=1 $.
if you can do that, then induction is the best method to prove this.

Or you can use ring theory and establish that the set of real numbers is a field w.r.t + and *. From which you can say that 1 is an identity element and hence,

$$
a.1=1.a=a
$$

use the right identity here, *i.e.*
$$
a.1=a
$$

since R is a field, it must have an inverse element w.r.t multiplication. As 1 is identity element, it is the inverse of itself.
$$
\therefore 1^{-1}=1
$$$$
\implies a.1^{-1}=a
$$$$
\implies \frac a 1 =a
$$

Comment: Induction is not exaclty something you can do with an uncountable set...

Comment: Its not at all clear to me how we'd use induction in this situation. Care to elaborate?

Comment: my idea was to do like this, define
$$
f(x)=\frac x 1 - x
$$$$
we\ need\ to\ prove\ f(x)=0 \forall x\in R
$$
Then proceed to check for x=1, x=2 
assume it is true for x, then check for x+1
but I guess that proves for the set of natural numbers. 
Anyways, since R is a field, the proof is straight forward.